# Issue with Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

This my code.
I get data from xml.
 But it's not working.. 
Please look it where is there error.
I can't find it.. I am working on it for more than a week...

But nothing:(

P.S. Sorry for my English..

This is my XML data..

```
 <marker>
<line id_line="1" colour="#ccc" width="4" users="line" coordinats="47.828979,40.974844;47.839451,40.985211;47.848377,40.981064;47.853699,40.984822">
<point lng="40.974844" lat="47.828979"/>
<point lng="40.985211" lat="47.839451"/>
<point lng="40.981064" lat="47.848377"/>
<point lng="40.984822" lat="47.853699"/>
</line>
</marker>
```

JavaScript:

```
function line() {
            var point=[];
            downloadUrl("line.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");                             
        var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");
        for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
        var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
        var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));
        var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName("point");

  alert (points[i].getAttribute("lat"));

 var pts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
               pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                   parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            }
            new google.maps.Polyline(pts,colour,width);
            pts.setMap(map);
          }




  google.maps.event.addListener(pointpath,'mouseover', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#3ADF00' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });
  });

     google.maps.event.addListener(pointpath,'mouseout', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#FF0040' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 2 });
  });




       var mpenc = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var contentString = "Status: " + status ;
  google.maps.event.addListener(pointpath,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(contentString);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });

 }

     });  
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too much code to look through. Can you narrow down your problem to some subset of this code? Are there any errors in your console that give line numbers or more information about what "not work" means?

Comment: What doesn't work? What's going wrong? What do you expect it to do; and what doesn't it do?

Comment: Hi brio! Stack Overflow isn't designed for you to post code and get people to spot errors in it. If you could describe in more detail what you expect your code to do, and what it actually does, you'd have a better chance of getting help. (Your English is fine though.)

Comment: sorry.. problem is: I cant get any data.. i put there  alert ("show me it work:"); also not working (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is xmlDoc supposed to be?

```
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");                             
    var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");
```

Looks like this line:

```
    var xml = data.responseXML;
```

should be:

```
    var xmlDoc = data.responseXML;
```

If that doesn't help, see [this tutorial in the Google Maps API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml), the section "Outputting XML with PHP" and the part about checking that the XML output works.

Make sure you have this line:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

And the headers include the correct content type.  Open the XML in your browser and/or run it through a validator (requestXML will be null if the XML is not valid).

[Example with slightly modified xml](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=SO_brio_question.xml)

Comment: thanks for answer.... everything is ok in my xml. this is my output. http://nn-gis.com/map/line.php  / your code so hard to understand :(

Comment: Did you read the first part of my answer?  If your XML is valid, that is probably the problem.  BTW - The code at my link is not intended to be simple, it is a general purpose parser, it even parses your [XML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://nn-gis.com/map/line.php) OK, even though it is a slightly different format from the target format.

Comment: thanks for answer. ok. it working script with API 2.. I want do it with API V2 .. api v2 code is here. http://jsfiddle.net/U7sqU/ ..  maybe i do it wrong?

Comment: The [Google Maps API v2 is deprecated and could stop working as early as May 19, 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), I don't think it is worth spending any time developing for it.

Comment: ok.. everything is working.. I found it on yours code examples.. thank you so much!